# Refine and filter with ajax in Wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress, filtering

I have an image gallery in wordpress and I would like to filter the images based on say colour and style similar to the [website](http://tinyurl.com/kdob27l)

Someone please pint me in the right direction or a plugin that can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try gallery bank plugin.

In the settings enable the filter by tag (way at the bottom), and then add the desired tags to the images. (i.e. red, bold, retro). You can add as many tags as you want.

The image gallery will display all tags for all images (in thumbnail view)

When you click them, the images will re-sort (based on the tag clicked) without the page reloading.

You can manipulate the data-filter attribute of the # link in the includes_before php file. This link drives the sorting behavior.